# Is it possible to detect via adb if a certain app crashed (and restarted)?

Tags: adb, crashes, google-play-services

In my tablet Google Play Services crash every often. They do restart automatically.

I'd like to know if it's possible to programmatically discover via ADB whether a restart happened or not.

I tried somehow by looking at the processes with

> adb shell ps | grep com.google.android.gms

but I wasn't able to realize 
anything interesting - like when the process started, so that I could compare it with a previous poll.

Thanks